# Haskell's function application operator ($) usage

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm reading a piece by Bartosz Milewski wherein he defines the following function:

```
instance Applicative Chan where
  pure x = Chan (repeat x)
  (Chan fs) <*> (Chan xs) = Chan (zipWith ($) fs xs)
```

Why is the function application operator in parenthesis? I understand this is normally done in order to use an infix function in prefix notation form, but I don't understand why, in this case, the function couldn't couldn't simply be expressed as `Chan (zipWith $ fs xs)`, and wonder what the difference between the two is.

*(if you still need context, refer to the [article](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/12/formula-1-go-functional/))*

Comment: Would it be any simpler if it was written as `Chan (zipWith id fs xs)`? It's exactly the same as the current implementation.

Comment: Remember that `($)` isn't some magical primitive operator: it's a function just like `(+)` and `or`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, `$` is being *passed in* to `zipWith`. It's the same as writing

```
zipWith (\ f x ->  f x) fs xs
```

Without parentheses, it would have been equivalent to

```
zipWith (fs xs)
```

which is not going to typecheck.

An operator in parentheses behaves exactly like a normal identifier. With the following definition:

```
apply = ($)
```

the code could have looked like

```
zipWith apply fs xs
```

Comment: Specifically, the grammar of haskell requires you to say `zipWith <expr>`, where `<expr>` is an expression. `($)` is the infix operator `$` converted to an *expression*, which is a bit different than "converted to prefix", and allows both usage as a prefix function and usage as an argument to other functions.